# Can't use realm framework in Swift 2 application

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm running the latest beta of El Capitan along with the latest Xcode 7 Beta.

I'm trying to import the Realm framework to use in my iOS application.  I've followed the specific instructions for the Swift 2 installation and imported the Realm and RealmSwift frameworks into the embedded binaries.

I copied the files over and my Framework Search Paths is set to $(SRCROOT) - recursive.

On trying to build I'm getting "No such module 'Realm'" and it starts giving build errors on getting JSON values

[image: Build Error]

I've tried importing RealmSwift instead and I receive this error

[image: Build Error 2]

I've done all the recommended steps, cleaning, deleting derivedData, even moved my source code to a new project all with the same error.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that both Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework exist in the root of source directory? It seems that the Realm.framework is missing in the Framework Search Paths.

Comment: Yep, they're definitely there.  It seems to be picking up RealmSwift if it knows it needs the other required modules, and they're both in the same directory so I'm not sure why Realm isn't being detected

Comment: At the first time, you may see the fake error message despite the build was successful. It might be resolved if you rebuild several times. And could you please try to build example projects in the release zip? https://realm.io/

Comment: Ran the examples as you asked and they seem to build fine.  I deleted my SearchPaths and re-added the same one, I've cleaned and build plenty of times and sometimes all the errors go away and it builds successfully, but suddenly if I start typing more they all pop right back up, which is what I found most strange

Comment: So I've played around with it some more and I get it to build all the time now but I'm still getting the error about the `missing required modules`

Comment: Can you get a build succeeded? I suspect it's Xcode's bug. The build is succeeded regardless of the message.

Comment: It succeeds but I was still unable to actually use it.  I've downgraded back to Yosemite recently and haven't got around to trying it again, so once I do I'll let you know the outcome

Comment: Tried it now being back on Yosemite and still receiving the same errors.  Created a new project from scratch again and receiving the exact same error.  Seems it just doesn't want to work on my system